# I need help to know why inheritance isn't working in this OOP example

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm getting the error "AttributeError: 'SavingsAccount' object has no attribute '_SavingsAccount__balance'" when I run this program and I can't work out why.  The error is linked to the savings.withdraw() method.  Any help would be welcome.  It will be clear that I am new to OOP.

```
import random

class Account:
    def __init__(self,holderName,balance):
        # generate a 4-digit PIN
        self.__PIN=''
        for x in range(4):
            self.__PIN+=chr(random.randint(48,57))
            
        # generate an 8-digit account number
        self.__accountNumber=''
        for x in range(8):
            self.__accountNumber+=chr(random.randint(48,57))
            
        self.__holderName = holderName
        self.__balance = balance
            
    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.__balance+=amount
        
    def getBalance(self):
        return(self.__balance)
    
    def setBalance(self,amount):
        self.__balance = amount

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.__balance -= amount
    
    def setAccountHolder(self,name):
        self.__holderName = name

    def getAccountHolder(self):
        return self.__holderName
            
    def PrintAccountInfo(self):
        print('\nPIN: {}'.format(self.__PIN))
        print('Account Number: {}'.format(self.__accountNumber))
        print('Account Holder: {}'.format(self.__holderName))
        print('Balance: £{:.2f}'.format(self.__balance))

  
class SavingsAccount(Account):
    def __init__(self, holderName, balance):
        super().__init__(holderName, balance)
        self.__withdrawals = 0
          
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.__withdrawals < 4:
            if self.__balance - amount >= 0.00:
                self.__balance -= amount
                self.__withdrawals += 1
            else:
                print('Cannot withdraw - insufficient funds.')
        else:
            print('You have exceeded the number of withdrawals for this session')
     
    def PrintAccountInfo(self):
        super().PrintAccountInfo()
        print('Withdrawals: {}'.format(self.__withdrawals))
            
# main program    
main = Account('Joe Smith',400)    
main.deposit(100)
main.PrintAccountInfo()

savings = SavingsAccount('Ann Brown',400)
savings.PrintAccountInfo()
savings.withdraw(200)
```

Comment: Add `python` tag.

Comment: There's almost certainly a duplicate for this, but read about [private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) in the docs. It's much more common to simply use names with a single `_` as its prefix to indicate private attributes. Name mangling is *specifically* for hiding a name from subclasses.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't fully understood private attributes in Python.  I'll use a getter method rather than trying to use self.__balance directly from the subclass.